# How to not let screen go to sleep in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.04

I think it is 17.10, I had 17.04 and it is the update that just came out. But I want to know how to not let the pc go to sleep.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56128/how-can-i-actually-change-my-power-management-settings

Comment: I went into power settings and turned off the inactive thing but it's not fixing it

Comment: Check your screensaver settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent lock is not working in Ubuntu 17.10 while watching YouTube videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969398/prevent-lock-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-17-10-while-watching-youtube-videos)